# How to resolve my 404 error when using hook menu?

Tags: routes

I've a custom module named workingmodule. I get a 404 when  visiting domain.com/workingmodule.

My module is enabled, and I cleared the cache. This id the code I am using in workingmodule.module.

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function workingmodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['workingmodule'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'workingmodule_blank_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
* Display the tagboard/custom content for page.
*/
function workingmodule_blank_page_callback() {
  print_r("test");
}
```

Why does domain.com/workingmodule return a 404 error?

Comment: Maybe its something with my local environment? I've restarted Apache, and didn't get anything out of that...

Comment: Please update your post with the error you founded each time you attempted to flush the cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested the code by adding that path and it works.

I suggest the following steps debug:

1. Make sure that Drupal is able to flush the cache without any problem by checking if there is any errors at admin/reports/dblog
2. If you didn't find any errors when you flushed the cache, try to add a `die('checking hook_menu')` on your hook_menu implementation to see if the hook is being executed.
3. If you are not going to pass any arguments to that callback I suggest you to remove the line `'page arguments' => array(),`
4. Check your Apache/NGINX settings, it could contain something that is affecting that path.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I was getting an error when clearing the cache! As dumb as I feel, I feel way better having this solved!

Comment: No worries, sometimes happens. If have a doubt, always check the logs. ;)

Comment: Flush cash is always the answer, even when you've already done it. Sums up Drupal right there.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `'page arguments' => array(),`

You're passing an array to a function that does not accept any arguments. Otherwise make your callback function function `workingmodule_blank_page_callback($arg)`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem but got an `500`. Had to uncomment the `RewriteBase` in Drupal's `.htaccess`:

```
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /
```